# Apple is Rejecting My App Changed Deployment Target from 6.0 to 8.0 in Xcode

Tags: ios

Apple sent me this:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "VampBlazer". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

INFO.PLIST MY FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>VampBlazer</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>AppIcon57x57.png</string>
        <string>AppIcon57x57@2x.png</string>
        <string>AppIcon60x60@2x.png</string>
        <string>AppIcon72x72@2x~ipad.png</string>
        <string>AppIcon72x72~ipad.png</string>
        <string>AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png</string>
        <string>AppIcon76x76~ipad.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>4.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen-iPad</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen-iPhone</string>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>Unity_LoadingActivityIndicatorStyle</key>
    <integer>-1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image]

Getting This Warning : also

_rootController.wantsFullScreenLayout = TRUE; "is deprecated in iOS 7.0)

```
I searched for  NSCameraUsageDescription this what showed up on this page 
#include "UnityAppController+ViewHandling.h"
#include "UnityAppController+Rendering.h"

#include "UI/OrientationSupport.h"
#include "UI/UnityView.h"
#include "UI/UnityViewControllerBase.h"
#include "Unity/DisplayManager.h"


// TEMP: ?
#include "UI/ActivityIndicator.h"
#include "UI/SplashScreen.h"
#include "UI/Keyboard.h"

extern bool _skipPresent;
extern bool _unityAppReady;


@implementation UnityAppController (ViewHandling)

#if !UNITY_TVOS
// special case for when we DO know the app orientation, but dont get it through normal mechanism (UIViewController orientation handling)
// how can this happen:
// 1. On startup: ios is not sending "change orientation" notifications on startup (but rather we "start" in correct one already)
// 2. When using presentation controller it can override orientation constraints, so on dismissing we need to tweak app orientation;
//      pretty much like startup situation UIViewController would have correct orientation, and app will be out-of-sync
- (void)updateAppOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    _curOrientation = orientation;
    [_unityView willRotateToOrientation:orientation fromOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown];
    [_unityView didRotate];
}
#endif

- (UnityView*)createUnityView
{
    return [[UnityView alloc] initFromMainScreen];
}
#if UNITY_TVOS
- (UnityViewControllerBase*)createUnityViewControllerForTVOS
{
    UnityDefaultTVViewController* controller = [[UnityDefaultTVViewController alloc] init];
    // This enables game controller use in on-screen keyboard
    controller.controllerUserInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return controller;  
}
#else
- (UnityViewControllerBase*)createAutorotatingUnityViewController
{
    return [[UnityDefaultViewController alloc] init];
}

- (UnityViewControllerBase*)createUnityViewControllerForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orient
{
    switch(orient)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:            return [[UnityPortraitOnlyViewController alloc] init];
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:  return [[UnityPortraitUpsideDownOnlyViewController alloc] init];
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:       return [[UnityLandscapeLeftOnlyViewController alloc] init];
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:      return [[UnityLandscapeRightOnlyViewController alloc] init];

        default:                                        NSAssert(false, @"bad UIInterfaceOrientation provided");
    }
    return nil;
}
- (UnityViewControllerBase*)createRootViewControllerForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    NSAssert(orientation != 0, @"Bad UIInterfaceOrientation provided");
    if(_viewControllerForOrientation[orientation] == nil)
    {
        _viewControllerForOrientation[orientation] =
                (UnityViewControllerBase*)[self createUnityViewControllerForOrientation:orientation];
    }
    return _viewControllerForOrientation[orientation];

}
#endif

- (UIViewController*)topMostController
{
  UIViewController *topController = self.window.rootViewController;
  while (topController.presentedViewController)
  {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
  }

  return topController;
}
- (UIViewController*)createRootViewController
{
#if UNITY_TVOS
    return [self createUnityViewControllerForTVOS];
#else
    UnityViewControllerBase* ret = nil;
    if(UnityShouldAutorotate())
    {
        if(_viewControllerForOrientation[0] == nil)
        {
            _viewControllerForOrientation[0] =
                    (UnityViewControllerBase*)[self createAutorotatingUnityViewController];
        }
        ret = _viewControllerForOrientation[0];
    }
    else
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = ConvertToIosScreenOrientation((ScreenOrientation)UnityRequestedScreenOrientation());
        ret = (UnityViewControllerBase*)[self createRootViewControllerForOrientation:orientation];
    }

    if(_curOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown)
        [self updateAppOrientation:ConvertToIosScreenOrientation(UIViewControllerOrientation(ret))];

    return ret;
#endif
}

- (void)willStartWithViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
{
    _unityView.contentScaleFactor   = UnityScreenScaleFactor([UIScreen mainScreen]);
    _unityView.autoresizingMask     = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    _rootController.view = _rootView = _unityView;
#if !UNITY_TVOS
    _rootController.wantsFullScreenLayout = TRUE;
#endif
}
- (void)willTransitionToViewController:(UIViewController*)toController fromViewController:(UIViewController*)fromController
{
    fromController.view = nil;
    toController.view   = _rootView;
}

#if !UNITY_TVOS
-(void)interfaceWillChangeOrientationTo:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation = _curOrientation;

    _curOrientation = toInterfaceOrientation;
    [_unityView willRotateToOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation fromOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
}
-(void)interfaceDidChangeOrientationFrom:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [_unityView didRotate];
}
#endif

- (UIView*)createSnapshotView
{
    // snapshot api appeared on ios7
    // BUT on ios7 tweaking hierarchy like that on going to background results in all kind of weird things when going back to foreground
    // so do snapshotting only on ios8 and newer
    return _ios80orNewer ? [_rootView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES] : nil;
}

- (void)createUI
{
    NSAssert(_unityView != nil, @"_unityView should be inited at this point");
    NSAssert(_window != nil, @"_window should be inited at this point");

    _rootController = [self createRootViewController];

    [self willStartWithViewController:_rootController];

    NSAssert(_rootView != nil, @"_rootView  should be inited at this point");
    NSAssert(_rootController != nil, @"_rootController should be inited at this point");

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

    // TODO: extract it?

    ShowSplashScreen(_window);

    NSNumber* style = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"Unity_LoadingActivityIndicatorStyle"];
    ShowActivityIndicator([SplashScreen Instance], style ? [style intValue] : -1 );
}

- (void)showGameUI
{
    HideActivityIndicator();
    HideSplashScreen();

    // make sure that we start up with correctly created/inited rendering surface
    // NB: recreateGLESSurface won't go into rendering because _unityAppReady is false
    [_unityView recreateGLESSurface];

    // UI hierarchy
    [_window addSubview: _rootView];
    _window.rootViewController = _rootController;
    [_window bringSubviewToFront:_rootView];

    // why we set level ready only now:
    // surface recreate will try to repaint if this var is set (poking unity to do it)
    // but this frame now is actually the first one we want to process/draw
    // so all the recreateSurface before now (triggered by reorientation) should simply change extents

    _unityAppReady = true;

    // why we skip present:
    // this will be the first frame to draw, so Start methods will be called
    // and we want to properly handle resolution request in Start (which might trigger surface recreate)
    // NB: we want to draw right after showing window, to avoid black frame creeping in

    _skipPresent = true;

    if (!UnityIsPaused())
        UnityRepaint();

    _skipPresent = false;
    [self repaint];

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)transitionToViewController:(UIViewController*)vc
{
    [self willTransitionToViewController:vc fromViewController:_rootController];
    _rootController = vc;
    _window.rootViewController = vc;

    [_rootView layoutSubviews];
}

#if !UNITY_TVOS
- (void)orientInterface:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orient
{
    if(_curOrientation == orient && _rootController != _viewControllerForOrientation[0])
        return;

    if(_unityAppReady)
        UnityFinishRendering();

    [KeyboardDelegate StartReorientation];

    [CATransaction begin];
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation oldOrient = _curOrientation;
        UIInterfaceOrientation newOrient = orient;

        [self interfaceWillChangeOrientationTo:newOrient];
        [self transitionToViewController:[self createRootViewControllerForOrientation:newOrient]];
        [self interfaceDidChangeOrientationFrom:oldOrient];

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = orient;
    }
    [CATransaction commit];

    [KeyboardDelegate FinishReorientation];
}

// it is kept only for backward compatibility
- (void)orientUnity:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orient
{
    [self orientInterface:orient];
}
#endif

#if UNITY_IOS
- (void)checkOrientationRequest
{
    if(UnityShouldAutorotate())
    {
        if(_rootController != _viewControllerForOrientation[0])
        {
            [self transitionToViewController:[self createRootViewController]];
            [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ScreenOrientation requestedOrient = (ScreenOrientation)UnityRequestedScreenOrientation();
        [self orientUnity:ConvertToIosScreenOrientation(requestedOrient)];
    }
}
#else
- (void)checkOrientationRequest
{
}
#endif

@end
```

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira in your edit, you should have also formatted the quote: better fix all the obvious issues in a post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `NSCameraUsageDescription` on info.plist as `string`
like

```
${PRODUCT_NAME} uses Camera
```

Comment: is that it? are you positive thanks so much Pravat for your feedback

Comment: yes that is, add that on plist file, build and resubmit

Comment: item 0 type string value ${PRODUCT_NAME} uses Camera

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/assets/images/2016/2016-07-03-001.png use like this , source useyourloaf.com

Comment: ? is that correct Pravat? I'm confused

Comment: I'm confused ? still i don't know how to write it :/

Comment: the new Xcode is making me frustrated  what do you mean useyourloaf.com- what would my source be

Comment: for simple, use "NSCameraUsageDescription" as key string, and put value as "${PRODUCT_NAME} uses Camera" , that's it. cheers

Comment: Okay Thanks ; let me try to see if i can do that ;

Comment: okay going to try and upload to App Store now :) Hopefully it works will keep you updated; thanks s o much